# How to validate the presence of multiple attributes if any is present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a model `Foobar`.

Foobar can have attributes as follows:

```
  create_table "foobars" do |t|
    t.integer   "a"
    t.integer   "b"
    t.integer   "c"
  end
```

In the form for creating new foobars, the user can add a number for **a, b, or c**. However, if they input a number for any of these attributes all others must be inputted as well. In other words if `a` is defined, I need to check that `b` and `c` are also defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated:
I would recommend [conditional validation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation). You could do something like:

```
class Foobar < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :a, presence: true, if: :interdependent_attributes_present?
  validates :b, presence: true, if: :interdependent_attributes_present?
  validates :c, presence: true, if: :interdependent_attributes_present?

  def interdependent_attributes_present?
    a.present? || b.present || c.present?
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, I actually have 8 attributes, so this method might become tricky to implement

Comment: Ok. I've altered my answer to allow for handling the greater complexity more easily.

Comment: Hi, I do have one remaining issue. Now I am able to create a Foobar without defining any of a, b, or c. Since I am accepting Foobars through a nested form, they are not required for form submission, and I don't want to create a Foobar if a Foobar has not been entered completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate the following statement in your validate method:

```
(a && b && c) || (!a && !b && !c)
```

That evaluates to true only if all of them are present, or all of them are nil.

Comment: So would I just write "validates" before this to make it work?